# May I know how to insert new added data in DataGridView to database?

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, insert

[image]

I need to know how to add the new inserted data row from `DataGridView` to database. No matter how rows have been inserted, when I click on Update Button, all the new inserted rows will be inserted into database.

Here is my code:

```
con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=tcp:SHEN-PC,49172\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=LSEStock;Integrated Security=True";
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

for (int i = 0; i>=dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
{

    String insertData = "INSERT INTO CostList(SupplierName, CostPrice, PartsID) VALUES (@SupplierName, @CostPrice, '" + textBox1.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertData, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierName", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostPrice", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartsID", textBox1.Text);
    da.InsertCommand = cmd;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

con.Close();
```

The above code has no respond after I clicking Update button. There is no error but nothing has been inserted in the database, the data shown in the picture is the original data that has already in my database.

Or anyone who has a better codes to insert all the new added rows of data into database, please do let me know. I will appreciate it.

Comment: In your insert script instead of textBox1.Text use @PartsID.

Comment: Please update your question with the suggested fixes to the query. Also, please include the output of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and any errors you get.

Comment: @Trisped, well, as I mentioned in the last part of my question, when I click on the update button, nothing happen, no errors no output no anything, but the database new inserted data is not in the database.

Comment: @J.S. What? If you mean edit of your post, then you can view all edit history by clicking a link at the edit message.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are using a `>=` when you should be using a `<=`

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i>=dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++ )
```

So your for loop never executes.  This should have been obvious if you traced through your code in the debugger.

Comment: i've tried, it will be adding the data unlimitedly, now that i've tried " for (int i = 0; i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++ ) "
it did add data into the database table but it also added the existing data which is "KLJ and CST" as shown above now are duplicated.

now i wanted to know is, which code can get only the new inserted rows of data into the database.

Comment: If your data is coming is in a DataSet/DataTable you can use the `DataBoundObject` property to get the bound `DataRow` and check it's `State` property.  Otherwise it depends on how you are getting the data into the grid.  You should open a different question on that topic.